# Perl - Piping gunzip Output to File::ReadBackwards

Tags: perl

I have a Perl project (CGI script, running on Apache) that has previously always used gunzip and tac (piping gunzip to tac, and piping that to filehandle) in order to accomplish its workload, which is to process large, flat text files, sometimes on the order of 10GB or more each in size. More specifically, in my use case these files are needing to be decompressed on-the-fly AND read backwards at times as well (there are times when both are a requirement - mainly for speed).

When I started this project, I looked at using `File::ReadBackwards` but decided on tac instead for performance reasons. After some discussion on a slightly-related topic last night and several suggestions to try and keep the processing entirely within Perl, I decided to give `File::ReadBackwards` another shot to see how it stands up under this workload.

Some preliminary tests indicate that it may in fact be comparable, and possibly even better, than tac. However, so far I've only been able to test this on uncompressed files. But it now has grabbed my interest so I'd like to see if I could make it work with compressed files as well.

Now I'm pretty sure I could probably unzip a file to *another* file, then read that backwards, but I think that would have terrible performance. Especially because the user has the option to limit results to X number for the exact reason of *helping* performance so I do not want to have to process/decompress the entirety of a file every single time I pull any lines out of it. Ideally I would like to be able to do what I do now, which is to decompress and read it backwards on-the-fly, with the ability to bail out as soon as I hit my quota if needed.

So, my dilemma is that I need to find a way to pipe output from gunzip, into `File::ReadBackwards`, if possible.

On a side note, I would be willing to give `IO::Uncompress::Gunzip` a chance as well (compare the decompression performance against a plain, piped gunzip process), either for performance gain (which would surprise me) or for convenience/the ability to pipe output to `File::ReadBackwards` (which I find slightly more likely).

Does anyone have any ideas here? Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. [File::ReadBackwards](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ReadBackwards) requires a seekable handle (i.e. a plain file and not a pipe or socket).

To use File::ReadBackwards, you'd have to first send the output to a named temporary file (which you could create using [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Temp)).

Comment: That's unfortunate - I was worried that might be the case. So it sounds like its either use a temp file, or don't use File::ReadBackwards (either stick w/ external commands as I am doing currently or take a different approach altogether as proposed by zdim). Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

While `File::ReadBackwards` won't work as desired, here is another take.

In the original approach you first `gunzip` before `tac`-ing, and the whole file is read so to get to its end; thus `tac` is there only for convenience. (For a plain uncompressed file one can get file size from file metadata and then seek toward the end of a file so to not have to read the whole thing.)

Then try the same, or similar, in Perl.  The [IO::Uncompress::Gunzip](https://perldoc.perl.org/IO/Uncompress/Gunzip.html) module also has `seek` method. It does have to uncompress data up to that point

> Note that the implementation of `seek` in this module does not provide true random access to a compressed file/buffer

but with it we still avoid copying uncompressed data (into variables) and so pay the minimal price here, to uncompress data in order to `seek`. In my timings this saves upward from an order of magnitude, making it far closer to system's `gunzip` (competitive on the order of 10Mb file sizes).

For that we also need the uncompressed size, which module's `seek` uses, which I get with system's `gzip -l`. Thus I still need to parse output of an external tool; so there's that issue.<sup>†</sup>

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip qw($GunzipError);

my $file = shift;
die "Usage: $0 file\n" if not $file or not -f $file; 

my $z = IO::Uncompress::Gunzip->new($file) or die "Error: $GunzipError"; 

my $us = (split ' ', (`gunzip -l $file`)[1])[1];  # CHECK gunzip's output
say "Uncompressed size: $us"; 

# Go to 1024 bytes before uncompressed end (should really be more careful
# since we aren't guaranteed that size estimate)
$z->seek($us-1024, 0);

while (my $line = $z->getline) { 
    print $line if $z->eof;
}
```

(Note: docs advertise `SEEK_END` but it didn't work for me, neither as a constant nor as 2. Also note that the constructor *does not fail* for non-existent files so the program doesn't `die` there.)

This only prints the last line. Collect those lines into an array instead, for more involved work.

For compressed text files on order of 10Mb in size this runs as fast as `gunzip | tac`. For files around 100Mb in size it is slower by a factor of two.  This is a rather rudimentary estimate, and it depends on all manner of detail.  But I am comfortable to say that it will be noticeably slower for larger files.

---

However, the code above has a particular problem with file sizes possible in this case, in tens of Gb.  The good *old* `gzip` format has the limitation, nicely stated in [gzip manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gzip/manual/html_node/Invoking-gzip.html#Invoking-gzip)

> The `gzip` format represents the input size modulo *2^32* [...]

Then sizes obtained by `--list` for files larger than 4Gb undermine the above optimization: We'll `seek` to a place early in the file instead of to near its end (for a 17Gb file the size is reported by `-l` as 1Gb and so we seek there), and then in fact read the bulk of the file by `getline`.

The best solution would be to use the known value for the uncompressed data size -- if that is known. Otherwise, if the compressed file size exceeds 4Gb then `seek` to its compressed size (as far as we can safely), and after that use `read` with very large chunks

```
my $len = 10*1_024_000;  # only hundreds of reads but large buffer

$z->read($buf, $len) while not $z->eof;

my @last_lines = split /\n/, $buf;
```

The last step depends on what actually need be done.  If it is indeed to read lines backwards then you can do `while (my $el = pop @last_lines) { ... }` for example, or `reverse` the array and work away. Note that it is likely that the last read will be far lesser than `$len`.

On the other hand, it could so happen that the last read buffer is too small for what's needed; so one may want to always copy the needed number of lines and keep that across reads.

The buffer size to read (`$len`) clearly depends on specifics of the problem.

---

Finally, if this is too much bother you can pipe `gunzip` and keep a buffer of lines.

```
use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote); 

my $num_lines  = ...;  # user supplied
my @last_lines;

my $cmd = shell_quote('gunzip', '-c', '--', $file);

my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', $cmd  // die "Can't open $cmd: $!";

push @last_lines, scalar <$fh>  for 0..$num_lines;  # to not have to check

while (<$fh>) { 
    push @last_lines, $_;
    shift @last_lines;
}
close $fh;

while (my $line = pop @last_lines) {
    print;  # process backwards
}
```

I put `$num_lines` on the array right away so to not have to test the size of `@last_lines` against `$num_lines` for every `shift`, so on every read. (This improves runtime by nearly 30%.)

Any hint of the number of lines (of uncompressed data) is helpful, so that we skip ahead and avoid copying data into variables, as much as possible.

```
# Stash $num_lines on array
<$fh> for 0..$num_to_skip;   # skip over an estimated number of lines
# Now push+shift while reading
```

This can help quite a bit, but depending on how well we can estimate the number of lines. Altogether, in my tests this is still slower than `gunzip | tac | head`, by around 50% in the very favorable case when I skip 90% of the file.

---

<sup>†</sup> The uncompressed size can be found without going to external tools as

```
my $us = do { 
    my $d; 
    open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file: $!";
    seek($fh, -4, 2)  and  read($fh, $d, 4) >= 4  and  unpack('V', $d) 
        or die "Can't get uncompressed size: $!";
 };
```

Thanks to mosvy for a comment with this.

If we still stick with using system's `gunzip` then the safety of running an external command with user input (filename), practically bypassed here by checking for that file, need be taken into account by using [String::ShellQuote](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::ShellQuote) to compose the command

```
use String::ShellQuote qw(shell_quote); 
my $cmd = shell_quote('gunzip', '-l', '--', $file);
# my $us = ... qx($cmd) ...;
```

Thanks to ikegami for comment.

Comment: FWIW, you can replace the external command with `my $us = do { my ($h, $d); open $h, '<', $file and seek $h, -4, 2 and read($h, $d, 4) >= 4 and unpack 'V', $d or die "cannot get uncompressed size" };`. And yes, this will be broken with multi-member gzip files ... no different from `gunzip -l $file` ;-) (but at least it doesn't interpolate a user supplied string in a shell command). Notice that that "size" is only modulo 2^32 (4G) of the real size.

Comment: Interpolating a user-supplied string can be achieved as follows: `use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote ); my $cmd = shell_quote('gunzip', '-l', '--', $file);  \`$cmd\``

Comment: @mosvy The user input is easily controlled (which it surely should be!).  But the other comment is critical since I completely forgot about that 4Gb screw, crucial here since files may actually be larger.   Edited

Comment: @dwillis77 Edited substantially.  Don't know how much it helps but should be worth looking over

Comment: @zdim Thank you very much for the ideas - lots of food for though here. I'll need some more time to chew through it all and try out my various options. But yes the overall goal is to return results (lines) in reverse (from the end of the file), up to an optional limit set by the user. And this result set may come from one or more files (depending on number of results returned from each).

Comment: @dwillis77 OK, thanks.  One simple thing you can always do is to pipe `gunzip` and keep a buffer of lines as it reads through the file. Then eventually process it (reverse) in Perl.  It's still a bit lower though.  I added a section with this.